# Prototype 1 Challenge in Unity - adding Rigidbody to game assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have added a Rigidbody to each of the obsticles in the Prototype 1 Challenge in Unity. The "player" (plane) game object already has a rigidBody attached. However, when I play the game the plane passes through the obsticles.

How can I make the obsticles solid. I want to use them as triggers to remove points from the player when they collide?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestions:**

If you use any collider as a trigger then other objects will pass through it no matter if they are colliders or triggers so just uncheck that property (in your case its box collider) uncheck all of 'is Trigger' then they will become the collider as you want them to be and after that you can have some script which detects collision to check if you collided with obstacle you remove the points from player.

Hope it works... Happy coding :)

Comment: Hello, I have unchecked ALL box colliders and triggers but the plane game object STILL passes through the obsticles as if they were not there....

Comment: then check if the plane is trigger or not, basically for now just turn off 'is Trigger' boolean of every collider that you want to collided to or collide from.